# Seeing email thread in email body on ipad, but not on pc

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, ipad

I have a user who looks at his Outlook email both on his ipad and his work pc. When he looks at an email on his pc the thread within the email body is missing (he only sees one or two previous replies). When he views the same email on his ipad he sees the entire thread of prior emails within the email body. Any clue why this is?

Edit:  To provide an example, here is how the email would appear on the ipad.

### (reply area)

to:dfkdfkdk
from:sdfjsdfj

dfjdjkkdfkldfkdfk

---

to:dfkdfkdk
from:sdfjsdfj

dfjdjkkdfkldfkdfk

---

to:dfkdfkdk
from:sdfjsdfj

dfjdjkkdfkldfkdfk

---

to:dfkdfkdk
from:sdfjsdfj

dfjdjkkdfkldfkdfk

and so on. Whereas in Outlook on his pc it would just show up as:

### (reply area)

to:dfkdfkdk
from:sdfjsdfj

dfjdjkkdfkldfkdfk

---

to:dfkdfkdk
from:sdfjsdfj

dfjdjkkdfkldfkdfk

so he's missing the rest of the messages. hope that is clear.

Comment: does he have the conversations feature turned on in Outlook?

Comment: checking with him now. hopefully if he doesn't it will work out. i'll update soon.

Comment: it did not change anything, but he's going to keep it on just in case.